# SWT Remove Filter

Tags: java, filter, swt

i try to remove a filter because I get the error: Widget is disposed.

My Filter:

```
disp.addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener() {

        public void handleEvent(Event e) {
            if(disp.isDisposed()){
                disp.removeFilter(SWT.KeyDown, this);
            }

            if (e.keyCode == SWT.CR) {
                       //....
            }

        }
    });
```

But I get the message even with the isDisposed If. I think I have to put it in the cancel and in the OK Buttons. But how do I get the listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to removeFilter from an already disposed widget.
Try this:

```
    if(!disp.isDisposed()){ // not disposed
        disp.removeFilter(SWT.KeyDown, this);
    }
```